# Which cameras were used prior to Apollo 11?

Tags: history, old-cameras, extraterrestrial-cameras

Which cameras were used on the missions prior to Apollo   11 ? I know that the moon landings used Hasselblad medium  format.

Answer (score 14):

According to [this NASA PDF](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/apollo.photechnqs2.pdf), Apollo 7 and 8 did not take hand-held cameras, instead using vehicle mounted Maurer or custom-built cameras.

Apollo 9 had a Hasselblad Superwide, Apollo 10 had no hand held cameras, and Apollos 11 through 13 had custom built Hasselblad Lunar Data Cameras. Apollos 11 and 12 also had a 'Closeup Stereo ALSCC' camera.

There is a complete report on the camera systems used in the Gemini and Apollo programs [here](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/apollo.photechnqs.htm).

Comment: Thanks for that , I raised the question as I had seen a pic of what i assumed was a 35mm camera and couldn't identify it